# Picture Slideshow as aspx?

Tags: document-library, picture-library, aspx, picture

I need some help in understanding what I am looking at. One of my colleagues showed me a file within a Document Library shown below:

[image]

When this file is selected it displays a slideshow if pictures similar to what a Picture Library Slideshow Web Part does. I was too embarrassed to ask how to create one. So I decided to ask here.

I also noticed looking at the properties that it is an aspx file. The pictures resided in a Picture Library called Golfing 2015 Pictures. I'm curious, how was this aspx file created which contains a slideshow of photos that belongs to the Golfing 2015 Pictures Library and then put the aspx file inside a Document Library. Can someone please clarify as to how I can achieve the same exact thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the icon I can say it is a web part page. A web part page is an aspx page. So he must have created a web part page and added a picture slideshow web part to that page.

Comment: Thanks! I actually stumbled upon that when I was playing around and figured it out as I went.